# 401 Error getting a list of service endpoints using REST API from TFS extension

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk, azure-devops-rest-api

I have developed a TFS extension for TFS 2017 on premises.
I need to get a list of the [service endpoint](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/endpoints/endpoints) within a project

I am using the following code inside a TFS extension ([code-hub](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/targets/overview))

```
private callTfsApi() {
    const vsoContext = VSS.getWebContext();
    let requestUrl = vsoContext.host.uri
        + vsoContext.project.id
        + "/_apis/distributedtask/serviceendpoints?api-version=3.0-preview.1";

    return VSS.getAccessToken().then(function (token) {
        // Format the auth header
        const authHeader = VSS_Auth_Service.authTokenManager.getAuthorizationHeader(token);

        // Add authHeader as an Authorization header to your request
        return $.ajax({
            url: requestUrl,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": authHeader
            }
        }).then((response: Array<any>) => {

            console.log(response);
        });
    });
}
```

On every request the server responds with a status of 401 (Unauthorized).

If I use postman and basic authentication the call to the service endpoints APIs works.

Also, using the same code but a different API call ([projects](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects)) works.

```
let requestUrl = vsoContext.host.uri + "_apis/projects?api-version=1.0";
```

Is there some sort of known bug related to the service endpoints APIs or maybe the extension must specify a [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/manifest#scopes)? (not sure which one to include though)

Comment: What's the detail of your error message info? Did you get a  Invalid Resource error?

Comment: Print out the token and use it in Postman to get the service endpoint, does it work?

Comment: That is exactly what I did and is not working with service endpoints. The same bearer token works with projects.

Comment: Have you tried the scope I mentioned?

Comment: I will give it a try after March 5. Thanks for the suggestion!!

Answer (score 0):

Service endpoints are **created at project scope**.  If you could query project info, you should also be able to query this.

You could try to add related scope `vso.project` in  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/manifest#scopes page see if  this do the trick.

Another way to narrow down this issue is directly using Rest API to call from code (not inside a TFS extension ) to see if the issue is related to extension side.

Comment: I did that. Using postman I am able to query the projects API with bearer token and using that token is not working with service endpoint API.

Comment: @JuanM.Elosegui Service endpoints are created at project scope. What's the result  if you  change the scope in the manifest (vss-extension.json). For this, try to add
`"scopes":
      [
      "vso.project"
      ]`

Comment: The same. I literally added every single scope without success.

Comment: @JuanM.Elosegui What's your detail error info, could your issue be similar to this one? Take a look  at this in GITHub https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api/issues/114  Moreover,  since you mentioned  `use postman and basic authentication the call to the service endpoints APIs works`  have you tried a `"Authorization": basicAuthHeader `

Answer (score 0):

Add scope: `vso.serviceendpoint_query`